# Firefox Web Browser : Input Type Text Inside Click On Not Stable

Tags: html, jquery, css, firefox

i want stable input box when i click on inside input box.
this code works on google chrome but not work in firefox web browser. i want same behaviour on firefox. i have no idea where is issue. please help me thanks.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

        var input = $(".block-search .block-content");
        input.hide();

        $('.block-search .block-title').click(function(){ 
            $('.block-search .block-content').toggle();
            $(".block-search .block-content .input-text").blur();
            
        });
        $(".block-search .block-content .input-text").on('click', function() {
            $(".block-search .block-content .input-text").focus();
            $('.block-search .block-content').show();
        });

        $(document).mouseup(function(e){
            $('.block-search .block-content').hide();
        });
    });
```

```css
.container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 50px auto 0;
        }
        .block-title{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="block block-search">
        <div class="block block-title"><strong>Click Input</strong></div>
        <div class="block block-content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="field search">                
                <div class="control">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." class="input-text" style="padding: 8px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$(".block-search .block-content .input-text").focus();` instead of `$(".block-search .block-content .input-text").blur();` for focusing when you click on "Click Input"

Comment: @KamranAllana, i have added your code, now  input box visible but text typing does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 
                var input = $(".block-search .block-content");
                input.hide();

                $('.block-search .block-title').click(function(){ 
                    $('.block-search .block-content').toggle();
                    $(".block-search .block-content .input-text").focus();
                });

                $(".input-text").click(function(e) {
                    $('.block-search .block-content').show();
                    $(this).focus();
                });

                $(document).mouseup(function(e){
                    if(!$(e.target).hasClass('input-text') ) {
                        $('.block-search .block-content').hide();
                    }
                });
            });
```

```css
.container {
            max-width: 600px;
            margin: 50px auto 0;
        }
        .block-title{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">

    <div class="block block-search">
        <div class="block block-title"><strong>Click Input</strong></div>
        <div class="block block-content" style="display: none;">
            <div class="field search">                
                <div class="control">
                    <input id="search" type="text" name="q" placeholder="Search here..." class="input-text" style="padding: 8px;">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i have check on firefox and chrome. i want 2 click. 
1st click on open input box and 2 click to input box for text type.

Comment: You want double clicks ? sorry couldn't got you would you please share little more.

Comment: no double clicks. i want no. of 2 clicks step by step clicks

Comment: please check my code in chrome then check on firefox you can better understand what i want to say.

Comment: Yes, I got you kindly check again I've edited the answer.

Comment: i have share video link :  https://streamable.com/z1x4ln

Comment: i have check your code in firefox. when i click on input text box, close automatically not stable

Comment: Kindly check it now, I've also tested on Firefox and it's now working fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251641/discussion-between-gaurav-and-kamran-allana).